# Receiving multiple webhook notification for Facebook Feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wampserver, webhooks

I am facing issue with Facebook Webhook for feed while messages are working perfectly. For one post i keep on getting multiple notification from Facebook. I have already raised a bug with Facebook and their team is saying that my server is failing to send back 200 OK HTTP status. Also in their doc i have found that

> "Your webhook callback should always return a 200 OK HTTP response when invoked by Facebook. Failing to do so may cause your webhook to be unsubscribed by the Messenger Platform."

My code goes like this:

```
<?php
$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

if ($verify_token === 'password')
{
echo $challenge;

}

/*........RECEIVING INPUT FROM fACEBOOK.........*/
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input') , true);
error_log(print_r($input, true));

/*after this i am calling AI and then replying back*/
```

Is there any way to send back 200 OK status before calling AI in php.

Comment: I have tried creating a dummy request from [link](http://requestmaker.com) and I am getting 200 as status.

Comment: PHP answers with 200 by default, if there where no severe errors preventing it from doing so (like an internal server error, which would result in a 500.) Enable proper error logging, and then check access and error log to find out how the actual requests Facebook makes are answered by your script.

Comment: I have error log at every step and all the steps are getting executed nicely and within time limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Workaround, I have stored the notification in DB and for every notification i am checking existing data (timestamp, senderId, post) in the DB to eliminate the duplicate post.

If anyone is having better option in terms of complexity please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I a similar issue and in my case I was subscribed to my test app and actual production app. Thus 2 events being sent